# How to send array data from Parent to Child using Observable in Angular properly?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

First, I need to send some json data from parent to child component, but I load the data from http request in ngOnInit event and when I submit the data in normal way, the data is not sent to my child component, here is my first try :

```
data: TransSalesOrder = new TransSalesOrder();

   ngOnInit(): void {

    if (this.dataId > 0) {
      const data: SelectItem = new SelectItem();
      data.id = this.dataId;
      const sb = this.transSalesOrderService.view(data).subscribe(response => {
        this.transSalesOrderForm.patchValue(response);
        this.data = response;

        if (this.transSalesOrderForm.get('isDeleted').value) {
          this.editButton = false;
          this.deleteButton = false;
          this.isDeleted = true;
        }
      }, err => {
        this.openSnackBar(err);
      });
      this.subscriptions.push(sb);
    }

}
```

Then in my parent html, I sent the data like this :

```
<app-trans-sales-order-detail-list [salesOrderDetailsInput]="data.transSalesOrderDetail"></app-trans-sales-order-detail-list>
```

Then when I console.log in the child component.ts :

```
@Input() salesOrderDetailsInput: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.salesOrderDetailsInput);
  }
```

It's print out 'undefined'

Then I think the parent is too late to load the data, and here is my second try, I need ngOnChanges event :

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes.salesOrderDetailsInput.currentValue);
  }
```

Then I can get my data that sent from parent, but I read somewhere in stackoverflow, some said there is async function needed to add from the parent value and the @Input in child component should retrieve as Observable, then I assume if I can do this, I will no longer need ngOnChanges, here is how I try :

In my parent code :

```
<app-trans-sales-order-detail-list [salesOrderDetailsInput]="data.transSalesOrderDetail | async"></app-trans-sales-order-detail-list>
```

But it give me error `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'` when compile and error `Argument type TransSalesOrderDetail[] is not assignable to parameter type Observable<unknown> | Promise<unknown>` in my Intellij Idea ide

Here is my child component.ts :

```
@Input() salesOrderDetailsInput: Observable<any>;
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: Is there a type for `transSalesOrderDetail`? You should use this as type for the child component's input - something like this: `@Input() salesOrderDetailsInput: TransSalesOrderDetail;`

Answer (score 1):

The member variable `this.data` is assigned a value asynchronously and holds an empty object by the time the binding `[salesOrderDetailsInput]="data.transSalesOrderDetail"` is executed. So it sends the current state of `transSalesOrderDetail` which is `undefined`.

IMO there is no need for `async` use here. You could try the following

**Option 1: `*ngIf`**

Conditionally render the child component tag using `*ngIf`

```html
<app-trans-sales-order-detail-list 
  *ngIf="!!data && !!data.transSalesOrderDetail"
  [salesOrderDetailsInput]="data.transSalesOrderDetail"
></app-trans-sales-order-detail-list>
```

Here the child component will not be rendered when the `transSalesOrderDetail` property isn't defined. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/6513921) for more info on double bang `!!` operator.

**Option 2: safe navigation operator `?.`**

Use safe navigation operator `?.` when accessing properties. It'll check if the property is defined in an object before trying to access it.

```html
<app-trans-sales-order-detail-list 
  [salesOrderDetailsInput]="data?.transSalesOrderDetail"
></app-trans-sales-order-detail-list>
```

Here the child component might be rendered but without binding to `transSalesOrderDetail`.

---

Having said that, I could provide some additional suggestions

When using `ngOnChanges` hook to read the changes to the `@Input` properties, it is better to check if the property is defined before trying to access it. It might not be an issue in a component with a single `@Input` property. But when there are multiple `@Input`s, it might happen some are defined and some aren't.

```js
@Input() salesOrderDetailsInput: any;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (!!changes && 
      !!changes.salesOrderDetailsInput && 
      !!changes.salesOrderDetailsInput.currentValue
  ) {
    console.log(changes.salesOrderDetailsInput.currentValue);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The async pipe actually works like a subscription made to an observable when you call an API or something to get data asynchronously. When you use an `async` pipe the left side of `|` should be an `observable`. Example:

**parent.component.html**

```
<ChildComponent [inputData] = "_data | async"></ChildComponent>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
public data = new BehaviorSubject(null);
public _data = this.selectedSubmission.asObservable();


ngOnInit(): {
  this.http.get(url).subscribe((respData:any)=>{
    this.data.next(respData);
  })
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() inputData: any;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log(this.inputData);
}
```

Note: You should use a service file to write all the API calls. The above example demonstrates how it should be done.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-to-child-communication-bp9a1m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for Input not working is, `data.transSalesOrderDetail` will be lead to an error on it's *first evaluation*, so try to add  [Elvis operator](https://www.joshmorony.com/safely-displaying-data-with-the-elvis-operator/). Once service in `ngOnInit()` is executed data will loaded and will properly as expected

Another way is, define variable and add it for input binding..

In **component.ts**

```
transSalesOrderDetail: TransSalesOrderDetail;

...
this.transSalesOrderForm.patchValue(response);
this.data = response;
this.transSalesOrderDetail = response.transSalesOrderDetail;
...
```

In **HTML**:

```
<app-trans-sales-order-detail-list [salesOrderDetailsInput]="data?.transSalesOrderDetail"></app-trans-sales-order-detail-list>


 // or with new variable <app-trans-sales-order-detail-list [salesOrderDetailsInput]="transSalesOrderDetail"></app-trans-sales-order-detail-list>
```

Better to add type for Input as well

```
@Input() salesOrderDetailsInput: TransSalesOrderDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `transSalesOrderDetail`  an observable in your parent. Then subscribe to this observable in your child.

```
<app-trans-sales-order-detail-list [salesOrderDetailsInput]="data.transSalesOrderDetail"></app-trans-sales-order-detail-list>
```

Then in your child,

```
@Input() salesOrderDetailsInput: any;
...
...

ngOnInit(): void {
  salesOrderDetailsInput.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Optionally, you can use an `async` pipe which would remove the necessity of subscribing - but there you will have to use the onChange event to get the latest data.,